# Unable to install agda via nix in macOS M1

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, apple-m1, agda, nix

Running

```
nix-shell -p agda
```

on macOS M1 (Monterey), compilation seems to run fine but linking fails with a segmentation error

```
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 139 (use -v to see invocation)
`cc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 139)
error: builder for '/nix/store/0zli7b0k7mdq3aj9yrfk546vr1a1mb34-Agda-2.6.2.2.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 10 log lines:
       > [399 of 401] Compiling Agda.Compiler.JS.Compiler ( src/full/Agda/Compiler/JS/Compiler.hs, dist/build/Agda/Compiler/JS/Compiler.o, dist/build/Agda/Compiler/JS/Compiler.dyn_o )
       > [400 of 401] Compiling Agda.Compiler.Builtin ( src/full/Agda/Compiler/Builtin.hs, dist/build/Agda/Compiler/Builtin.o, dist/build/Agda/Compiler/Builtin.dyn_o )
       > [401 of 401] Compiling Agda.Main        ( src/full/Agda/Main.hs, dist/build/Agda/Main.o, dist/build/Agda/Main.dyn_o )
       > Preprocessing executable 'agda' for Agda-2.6.2.2..
       > Building executable 'agda' for Agda-2.6.2.2..
       > [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/main/Main.hs, dist/build/agda/agda-tmp/Main.o )
       > Linking dist/build/agda/agda ...
       > /nix/store/l1vm9w0y2fdav63xk2nfrwgzrg30hm5x-clang-wrapper-11.1.0/bin/ld: line 256:  1241 Segmentation fault: 11  /nix/store/gwm9iadcyybh7gc4q6djvaz4fb40i90c-cctools-binutils-darwin-949.0.1/bin/ld ${extraBefore+"${extraBefore[@]}"} ${params+"${params[@]}"} ${extraAfter+"${extraAfter[@]}"}
       > clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 139 (use -v to see invocation)
       > `cc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 139)
```

I did run into linking issues with other Haskell packages in recent versions of macOS, where `ghc` couldn't find `libffi` or `zlib`, and I had to set env variables, eg

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include/ffi"¬
```

However, In the case of agda, from the error message it's not obvious to me what the issue is: is it caused by a C lib that the linker cannot locate, and if yes how can i discover which one? is it a problem with M1? is `nix-shell -p agda` suppose to work on M1?

Comment: No program should segfault, not even in the error conditions you describe. This could be caused by a programming mistake in the linker (possibly triggered by "unusual" input), or it could be a hardware problem, such as a storage corruption, which you can pretty much rule out with `nix-store --verify --check-contents --repair` and then trying again.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally managed to find a github issue tracking the problem (it wasn't that easy to find): https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/149692#issuecomment-1177684790

According to the ticket, the only available workaround at the moment is to compile for x86_64 and use Rosetta